# Create kind of carousel Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, methods, computed-properties

So, I have a dashboard where I want to display some cards. There should only be four visible at a time and when clicking on the arrow you just want to move one step to the next card. So let's say cards 1-4 are showing and when clicking the right arrow you should be able to see 2-5. Right now I only have that when you click the right arrow you jump pass 1-4 and go straight to 5-10.

So right now I have this:

```
computed: {
    cardsToDisplay(): Status[] {
        return this.cards.slice(this.page * 4, (this.page + 1) * 4)
    },
},
methods: {
    setCards(no: number) {
        this.page = this.page + delta
    },
},
```

And in the template the left and right arrow buttons look like this:

```
        <v-icon v-if="page !==" class="black--text font-weight-bold" 
          @click="setPage(-1)">
          chevron_left</v-icon>

        <v-icon
            v-if="columns.length > (page + 1) * 4"
            class="black--text font-weight-bold"
            @click="setPage(1)"
            >chevron_right</v-icon
        >
```

But how can I make it just move to the next card? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
computed: {
    cardsToDisplay(): Status[] {
        return [...this.cards, ...this.cards].slice(this.cards_pos, this.cards_pos + 4)
    },
},
methods: {
    prev() {
        this.cards_pos = (this.cards_pos + this.cards.length - 1) % this.cards.length;
    },
    next() {
        this.cards_pos = (this.cards_pos + 1) % this.cards.length;
    },
},
```

With `[...this.cards, ...this.cards]` you ensure that the carousel is cyclic without much code.
With the remainder operator you ensure your `card_pos` is always less than the number of cards. With decrementing, you need to add the array length, to prevent going into the negatives.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    cards_pos: 0,
    cards: new Array(10).fill(null).map((e, i) => ({
      img: "https://picsum.photos/id/" + (i * 10) + "/200",
      text: "Card #" + (i + 1)
    }))
  }),
  computed: {
    cardsToDisplay() {
      return [...this.cards, ...this.cards].slice(this.cards_pos, this.cards_pos + 4)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    prev() {
      this.cards_pos = (this.cards_pos + this.cards.length - 1) % this.cards.length;
    },
    next() {
      this.cards_pos = (this.cards_pos + 1) % this.cards.length;
    },
  },
}).mount("#app")
```

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.cards > * {
  width: 25%;
}

.cards > * img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="prev">
    &lt;&lt;
  </button>
  <button @click="next">
    &gt;&gt;
  </button>
  <ol class="cards">
    <li v-for="card in cardsToDisplay">
      <img :src="card.img" />
      <p>
        {{ card.text }}
      </p>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! But on my 'next' button, how should I best write my if statement? Cause depending on who is logged in, it can be different amount of cards. So with:


        `<v-icon v-if="columns.length - 1 > page + 3" class="black--text font-weight-bold" @click="setPage(1)">chevron_right</v-icon>`

So this works now, but what if I have more cards or less cards? Will this work regardless of how many cards I have? And can I write it in a better way? :)

Comment: And it also worked when I only did `return this.columns.slice(this.page, this.page + 4)`
So do I really need the spread operator? :)